# How to achieve argument and path dependent type parametrization in constructor?

Tags: scala, generics, inner-classes, path-dependent-type

(using scala 2.11.12)

Why does this compile?

```scala
  sealed trait Inner

  sealed trait Outer {
    sealed trait I extends Inner
  }

  case object OuterA extends Outer {
    case object Inner1 extends I
    case object Inner2 extends I
  }

  case object OuterB extends Outer {
    case object Inner1 extends I
  }

  class Data[O <: Outer](outer: O, inner: O#I)
  // I expected this not to compile but it actually does
  val data = new Data(OuterA, OuterB.Inner1)
```

Why does this not compile?

```scala
  sealed trait Inner

  sealed trait Outer {
    type I <: Inner
  }

  case object OuterA extends Outer {
    sealed trait OuterAInner extends Inner
    override type I = OuterAInner
    case object Inner1 extends OuterAInner
    case object Inner2 extends OuterAInner
  }

  case object OuterB extends Outer {
    sealed trait OuterBInner extends Inner
    override type I = OuterBInner
    case object Inner1 extends OuterBInner
  }

  class Data[O <: Outer](outer: O, inner: O#I)
  // I expected this to compile but it actually does not
  val data = new Data(OuterA, OuterA.Inner1)
  // type mismatch;
  //   found   : com.transparencyrights.ermine.model.V1.OuterA.Inner1.type
  //   required: ?#I
  //  Note that Inner1 extends Any, not AnyRef.
  //  Such types can participate in value classes, but instances
  //  cannot appear in singleton types or in reference comparisons.
  //    val data = new Data(OuterA, OuterA.Inner1)
```

What I want to achieve is a unique `Data` constructor that takes two arguments, an `Outer` and an `Inner`, with the `Inner` type restricted to an `Inner` subtype dependent on the given `Outer` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On both cases the problem is that `O#I` does not do what you want it to do.
It really does not refer to the `I` inside the specific `O` you have, but rather to the generic one inside `Outer`.

You can fix both snippets using **Path dependent types** and **Generalized type constraints**.

## Case 1

```
sealed trait Inner

sealed trait Outer {
  sealed trait I extends Inner
}

final case object OuterA extends Outer {
  final case object Inner1 extends I
  final case object Inner2 extends I
}

final case object OuterB extends Outer {
  final case object Inner1 extends I
}

final class Data[O <: Outer, I <: O#I] private (outer: O, inner: I)

object Data {
  final def apply[O <: Outer, I <: O#I](outer: O, inner: I)(implicit ev: I <:< outer.I): Data[O, I] =
    new Data(outer, inner)
}

val data = Data(OuterA, OuterB.Inner1) // Does not compile.
val data = Data(OuterA, OuterA.Inner1) // Does compile.
```

## Case 2

```
sealed trait Inner

sealed trait Outer {
  type I <: Inner
}

final case object OuterA extends Outer {
  override final type I = OuterAInner

  sealed trait OuterAInner extends Inner

  final case object Inner1 extends OuterAInner
  final case object Inner2 extends OuterAInner
}

final case object OuterB extends Outer {
  override final type I = OuterBInner

  sealed trait OuterBInner extends Inner

  final case object Inner1 extends OuterBInner
}

final class Data[O <: Outer, I <: O#I] private (outer: O, inner: I)

object Data {
  final def apply[O <: Outer, I <: O#I](outer: O, inner: I)(implicit ev: I <:< outer.I): Data[O, I] =
    new Data(outer, inner)
}

val data = new Data(OuterA, OuterA.Inner1) // Does compile.
val data = new Data(OuterA, OuterB.Inner1) // Does not compile.
```

---

Now, since the examples does not show how do you want to use the **Data** class and the **outer** & **inner** fields, this may not be enough, but hope it helps you.
If you have any doubts, do not hesitate on asking on the comments.

Comment: Actually it works without the generalized type constraints `(implicit ev: I <:< outer.I)` in both case (tested in Scastie with scala 2.11, 2.12 and 2.13). The second generic type parameter `I <: O#I` is sufficient. It looks like `O#I` in the context of a generic type parameter bound behaves differently from when used as a parameter type, do you have any hint on this?

Comment: @M.Karassev Uhm, sorry but no. You can also use two argument list too, like `final def apply[O <: Outer](outer: O)(inner: outer.I)`.

Comment: This compiles as stated in the comments or am I missing something? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/veLlWOvgTSOTd6wLaPty8w

Comment: @M.Karassev In this case, it seems you do not even need the companion object of **Data**: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Iw0K2xrdQoWjcKVNwy9i8Q/2 - But as I said, the trick is in how do you want to use all this things.